# What is a good size (# of rows) to partition a table to really benefit?

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, database-partitioning

I.E. if we have got a table with 4 million rows.

Which has got a `STATUS` field that can assume the following value: `TO_WORK`, `BLOCKED` or `WORKED_CORRECTLY`.

Would you partition on a field which will change just one time (most of times from to_work to worked_correctly)? How many partitions would you create?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of rows in a table isn't generally a great metric to use to determine whether and how to partition the table.

What problem are you trying to solve?  Are you trying to improve query performance?  Performance of data loads?  Performance of purging your data?

Assuming you are trying to improve query performance?  Do all your queries have predicates on the `STATUS` column?  Are they doing single row lookups of rows?  Or would you want your queries to scan an entire partition?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to improve query performance. 
The table has about 5.000 insert every day. I'm just interested in not deteriorating this performance while improving massive error extraction (this kind of query are related to field STATUS and TYPE).
It is readed many times a day searching always by status (every record with a certain status must be processed and then the status is updated. 99% of times it goes to the final status. The other times, there was an error, and we must understand how to solve it).
I'd like to enhance performance in massive rows lookup.

Answer (score 19):

The absolute number of rows in a partition is not the most useful metric.  What you really want is a column which is stable as the table grows, and which delivers on the potential benefits of partitioning.  These are: availability, tablespace management and performance.

For instance, your example column has three values.  That means you can have three partitions, which means you can have three tablespaces.  So if a tablespace becomes corrupt you lose one third of your data.  Has partitioning made your table more available?  Not really.

Adding or dropping a partition makes it easier to manage large volumes of data.  But are you ever likely to drop *all the rows* with a status of `WORKED_CORRECTLY`?  Highly unlikely.  Has partitioning made your table more manageable?  Not really.

The performance benefits of partitioning come from query pruning, where the optimizer can discount chunks of the table immediately.  Now each partition has 1.3 million rows.  So even if you query on `STATUS='WORKED_CORRECTLY'` you still have a huge number of records to winnow.  And the chances are, any query which doesn't involve STATUS will perform worse than it did against the unpartitioned table.  Has partitioning made your table more performant?  Probably not.

So far, I have been assuming that your partitions are evenly distributed.  But your final question indicates that this is not the case.  Most rows - if not all - rows will end up in the `WORKED_CORRECTLY`.  So that partition will become enormous compared to the others, and the chances of benefits from partitioning become even more remote.

Finally, your proposed scheme is not elastic.  As the current volume each partition would have 1.3 million rows.  When your table grows to forty million rows in total, each partition will hold 13.3 million rows.  This is bad.

So, what makes a good candidate for a partition key?  One which produces lots of partitions, one where the partitions are roughly equal in size, one where the value of the key is unlikely to change and one where the value has some meaning in the life-cycle of the underlying object, and finally one which is useful in the bulk of queries run against the table.

This is why something like DATE_CREATED is such a popular choice for partitioning of fact tables in data warehouses.  It generates a sensible number of partitions across a range of  granularities (day, month, or year are the usual choices).  We get roughly the same number of records created in a given time span.  Data loading and data archiving are usually done on the basis of age (i.e. creation date).  BI queries almost invariably include the TIME dimension.

Comment: This answer is very informative for me, thanks.